# Android Stretch columns evenly in a TableLayout

Tags: android

I am displaying a table of values in my android application, and would like the columns to be distributed evenly in terms of size , instead of sizing according to content.

Been playing around with stretchColumns but couldn't manage to figure out the right combination, Any Ideas?

Comment: What was wrong with stretchColumns? Were some of the columns "overflowing"?

Comment: The I want them all to be the same size but they seem acquire different sizes between them.

Comment: I know... what I'm trying to figure out is if one of the views is bigger than the area you're wanting to allot for it's column.

Comment: Same here, I'm trying to figure out how to hard limit the width of each column and set it to be even with the rest and have content of each column stretch to a maximum of its allotted width but not wider.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I had the same problem - I always only entered one number in `android:stretchColumns`, but you have to enter all columns that should be stretched. So if you have three columns, you have to write:

```
android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
```

Or write:

```
android:stretchColumns="*"
```

Then all columns will have the same size. As a reminder, `android:stretchColumns` is an attribute for the `TableLayout` element.

Comment: i m trying to display 7 col value in android but dynamically from the class... but i when installing on the android ph. and keep round ph. it cant stretch column as well as xml static.

Comment: and how we would do this during runtime?

Comment: UPDATE: pTable.setColumnStretchable(1, true); pTable.setColumnShrinkable(0, true);

Comment: This seems to be true until the columns frequently change its size

Answer (score 23):

You need to set BOTH `android:layout_width="0dip"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for each view within a table row. I think this works because the weights determine the proportion of the EMPTY SPACE in the row used by the respective views, and since the width of all views is set to `0dip`, the whole row is empty space, and hence with equal weights the views are all allocated the same proportion of the WHOLE width.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. This sets the size of the columns to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `android:layout_weight` for the columns

Answer (score 2):

You control the size of the columns by the size of their contents. If you want them all to be the same size, set that up via `android:layout_width` in the appropriate cells.

Comment: if the contents are dynamic and i don't know the size layout width won't work. is there any other way

Answer (score -2):

Whoever is still looking for solution, for me: 
setting columns both shrinkable and stretchable did the trick. 
I had pretty much the same problem as OP.

Comment: For me, it's combining your answer + linitbuff's answer together.