# LinearLayout with 3 children of variable dimension

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having an issue building an Android XML layout with three children (two of them with variable dimension), having one of those children priority when spanning its width.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="bla 1 bla 1 bla 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=", " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="bla 2 bla 2 bla 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The issue is, I need this to be displayed like so: "bla 1 bla 1 bla 1, bla 2 bla 2 bla 2". With the requirement that, when there's not enough space only the firstTextView shrinks its width (something like: "bla 1 bla..., bla 2 bla 2 bla 2"). Keep in mind that the thirdTextView has variable width, so it could be containing only "bla 2" and has to be right  next to the secondTextView, which in turn has to be to the right of the firstTextView.

I'm trying to avoid having to adjust widths programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Your LinearLayout doesn't specify an orientation.

Comment: It doesn't have to. It's horizontal by default (which is what's intended).

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your first textView:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

This will make the View take the remaining space when the 2 other have their content wrapped

Answer (score 1):

Make sure each view adds layout_weight, like this

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

You can also play around with the value, instead of one, and get different sizes of views

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using the `layout_weight` attribute for these views. `layout_weight` controlls how excess, i.e. unused, pixles are attributed between views. It allows you to set a weighting, like a percentage, of how those views will be allocated unused pixles.

Because you are using these views in a horizontal row, set the `layout_width` of the ones you want to have variable size to 0dp. Then add a `layout_weight` attribute to adjust how the size vaires until it looks like you want.

Comment: I've tried working with the weights, the thing is, (since the textviews will occupy any extra space) the text won't be displayed as intended, which is "bla 1 bla 1 bla 1, bla 2 bla 2 bla 2". It will get spaced, from the firstTextView to the secondTextView and then to the thirdTextView.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you only set layout_weight on the child elements of variable size only those will adjust to take up the unused space. If you just use layou_width=wrap_content on those which you don't want expanding, they will not expand to fill the space.

Comment: Only the secondTextView won't have its content varying. Both the first and the third textviews will. By setting the weight on these two textviews if there's more than enough space, the first textview will expand its width, resulting in spacing between the first and the second textviews (breaking the "bla 1 bla 1 bla 1, bla 2 bla 2 bla 2" display that's pretended).

Comment: Can't you just control the positioning of the text within the view with `gravity`? If you're trying to give the illusion that view1 is part of view2 such that the comma is part of the sentence, can you allign the text to the right such that it is against that side of the view rather than the left or center?

Comment: I don't think so. The desirable appearance would be that the three textviews are part of the same sentence. I don't think I can do that by just adjusting the gravity, since it's left for all of them because I want the content of all the three textviews to be in sequence. Adjusting the gravity to the right would add another issue when having too much space.

Comment: then why not use 5 textviews - the 3 you have now all set to wrap content and then two fillers - one on either side - set to width 0dp and weight 1. This way those 2 will split the space not filled equally and the others remain together

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'll want to specify the LinearLayout orientation:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

But also, try using **weights** in your TextViews:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

(especially in the 2nd and 3rd TextViews. Try other values instead of "1" as well, to test).

Also, if you want to **stretch** columns, try using **TableLayout**, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666685/android-stretch-columns-evenly-in-a-tablelayout).