# Showing all TableRows on a smaller screen

Tags: android, layout, view

I developed my app on a 5 inches smartphone now I have a problem with smaller screens. I tested it on my HTC wildfire and there, the last two rows aren´t shown. The whole thing is a table with 6 rows and 4 columns, in every field is a button. 
All the buttons must be on one screen (not scrollable) and the button should look big enough on all screens.

I developed everything using dp and even because of that I don´t know why I have this problem now. 
Here is my xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"


        android:background="@drawable/willi"
         />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"
/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
             android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"

        android:background="@drawable/willi"
         />


    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp">



         <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:background="@drawable/willi"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"
   />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"
         />

        </TableRow>
       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" >


       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:background="@drawable/willi" />
    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:background="@drawable/willi" />

    </TableRow>



              <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" >


       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi" />
    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:background="@drawable/willi" />

    </TableRow>

      <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" >


       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:background="@drawable/willi" />
    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" >


       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button21"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:background="@drawable/willi" />
    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button22"
                 android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button23"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/willi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:background="@drawable/willi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPunktewaehrend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text=" " />


    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do not use any db or anything for width and height .. same time wrap is also the dangerous. replace all the height in db with fill_parent

Comment: for all buttons? What does fill_parent do exactly? If I do so, the buttons will be shown as big as they are on every screen I think?!

Comment: yes of course set fill_parent for every table row then the table layout height to match_parent, so the page is set for all screens .

Answer (score 1):

You can't use fixed widths if you are targeting multiple screen sizes. You'll need to use the `TableLayout`'s column stretching feature to dynamically adjust the column width of each view in the `TableRow`.

Comment: What do you mean with TableLayout´s column stretching feature? I´m using it the first time, can you give me an example?

Comment: This is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666685/android-stretch-columns-evenly-in-a-tablelayout.

Comment: Is this instead of the layout_width and layout_weight attributes?

Comment: Yes, you would no longer want to set fixed values for the width and height.

Comment: Am I right if I think this puts my grid on the whole screen and the buttons in it are streched then?

Comment: You can chose which view columns you want to stretch. If the column with the buttons is not stretched, it should snap back to it's original width, or the width you define.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47088/discussion-between-user896692-and-ross-squires)