# Always shown last column in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

Let's assume we have `TableLayout` with 3 columns, something like this:

[image]

Here is green border that means device screen space and red overlapping area is a space behind the screen.

So my goal is to make 3rd (most right one in particular case) column prioritized and always fully shown, just like so:

[image]

As you could see for now 2nd column has shrinked to free space for last column. Any ideas on how to reach such behavior?

Thanks.

**UPD1:**
Approximate basic XML layout for such table could look so:

```
<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
                android:text="header0"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="header1"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="header2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
                android:text="column0_value"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="column1_value"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="column2_value"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>
    <!--More rows here-->
</TableLayout>
```

**UDP2**
Some kind of solution is to use `android:shrinkColumns="0, 1"`, this will shrink content of other columns and show full last one. But goal is to show full content of all columns that may be fit before last column too.

Comment: can you show your xml layout for this.

Comment: In real case this table builds in code, so I dont have it. But for general problem it's better to find solution for regular xml first.

Comment: can you post your xml please ?

Comment: you can put weight to table fields and wrapping contens of them if they are wider.

Comment: @Metaphore did you tried stretch column attribute in tableLayout. See this question it might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666685/android-stretch-columns-evenly-in-a-tablelayout

Comment: @Darkie yep, stretch on last column doesn't make any effect.

Comment: @Metaphore ok seeing your xml code did you tried given width="wrap_content" to the textview's and also add  android:singleLine="true" to the textview so that they don't go to the next line ...

Comment: @Darkie they take it by default

Comment: and also set `android:stretchColumns="0"` to `tablelayout`