# Android : How to resize layouts in order to fit various screen

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my normal/activity.xml layout file (*I only post normal/activity.xml because other .xmls are pretty similar to that, only some sizes change for buttons, in dp*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/activity_main_background"
tools:context="com.jj.calculator.MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_area"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:gravity="right|bottom"
    android:foregroundGravity="right|bottom"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:text="@string/screen_text"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:lines="1"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="*"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="("
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text=")"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="^"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/c_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="C"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/equal_button"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also large/activity.xml and xlarge/activity.xml layouts for the specified by google "large" and "xlarge" screen dimensions. But when I am editing my .xml files, I only get one screen as representating sample. As a result, my layouts appear correctly only in screen sizes that have the exact size of the screen samples shown for each .xml file. How to make my app work in all different screen sizes? I appreciate any help.

Comment: In Android Studio, you can change the device that shows the preview.

Comment: Yes I know but I have only one xml file for screen sizes that may vary 2 inches.

Comment: Okay, but inches don't matter in screen size layout. Density and pixels do.

Comment: Okay, but why this does not work?

Comment: Why what does not work? If you want to have different widget sizes for different screen densities, then you have to actually edit the values in those XML files. Otherwise, having only one "normal" main layout does do the scaling correctly when you use `dp` sizing

Comment: Maybe you should look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666685/android-stretch-columns-evenly-in-a-tablelayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want your application to appear exactly the same when you  View it on large screen versus an extra large screen.    I have a similar situation thyat I worked through and was able to accomplish it with a single set of layout files for my application by using several values folders with different resource qualifiers.  In my case, I chose to use the smallest width qualifiers instead of the large and extra-large qualifiers    For example, since I wanted my application to always be in landscape mode, I created one layout-land folder that all of my layout files  are in .  I then created several values folders that had two resource qualifiers on each. The first resource qualifier was the smallest width qualifier and the second was the density.    For example, the first values folder was values-sw320dp-mdpi.  I used a combination of three smallest with groups, 320, 600 and 720.  For each of these, I created separate values folders for the different densities from mdpi - xxxhdpi.  Yes, this is a lot of resource folders, but it allows you to have a dimensions file that will specifically size and position all of the elements where they need to be based on the two factors you need to be concerned with, device size in dp and device density

Comment: Thanks for replying. Your answer is technically correct, but I'm wondering if there are easier ways. Anyway I will try it.